# Cells not appearing in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I don't understand why my cells aren't showing:

```
class MenuBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "pouet"

    lazy var customCollectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
        let cv  = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self

        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        customCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        addSubview(customCollectionView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: customCollectionView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: customCollectionView)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = customCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        print("test")

        return cell
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Now my `print("test")` is not showing either, meaning that the method is actually not called, right? So what is wrong ?

Comment: And here's a screenshot of the debugger tool : https://tof.cx/image/FfbH1

Comment: put something in your cells, otherwise theres nothing to show

Comment: Stil, there's a default black background, and default width and height, so there should be something to show. And also, it would print 'test'.

Comment: Try removing the following line: `customCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)` (in `viewDidLoad()`).

Comment: Yeah I tried that… But nope ! Still no cells in sight ! And no print confirmation either… I'm getting crazy!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this line of code:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
```

To:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
```

[UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout) is abstract class you can't use it directly.

Comment: @TrungAnhPham well spotted. I was looking at that for 10 minutes and didn't see it

Comment: Thank the stack gods! I have been trying to figure out this issue for a few hours!

Comment: 2 1/2 years later, you just saved me. Appreciate it!